# Tabulate XML file adding the relation of parent nodes number in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have the following code trying to parse a XML file and convert to table form.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('smp.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for text in root.iter('text'):
    print(text.attrib)

for text in root.iter('text'):
    print(text.text)
```

Below is the output I'm getting so far but is far from my desired output, since I´m new to python and 
I don't know how to organize these output to show tabulated them and additionally add the columns to the left for `page`, `row` and `column` parent elements
corresponding to each text/attribute.:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('smp.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>>
>>> for text in root.iter('text'):
...     print(text.attrib)
...
{'width': '71.04', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '83.42', 'x': '121.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '101.07', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '124.82', 'x': '121.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '140.31', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '207.65', 'x': '121.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '24.36', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '69.62', 'x': '85.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '95.42', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontStyle': 'Bold', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '239.45', 'x': '276.29', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '229.57', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '266.81', 'x': '121.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '155.71', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '266.81', 'x': '353.94', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '165.10', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '294.41', 'x': '85.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '14.39', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '294.41', 'x': '253.43', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '255.64', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '294.41', 'x': '271.04', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '432.97', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '501.43', 'x': '85.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '363.44', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '69.62', 'x': '85.10', 'height': '12.00'}
{'width': '382.36', 'fontName': 'Arial', 'fontSize': '12.0', 'y': '83.42', 'x': '85.10', 'height': '12.00'}

>>> for text in root.iter('text'):
...     print(text.text)
...
achene
capsule
caryopsis
cypsela
fibrous drupe
follicle
legume
loment
nut
samara
schizocarp
silicle
utricle
```

This is my expected output:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════╦════════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║ page ║ index ║ row ║ column ║    text    ║ fontName ║ fontSize ║   x    ║   y    ║ width  ║ height ║ fontStyle ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║    0 ║     0 ║     ║        ║            ║          ║          ║        ║        ║        ║        ║           ║
║    1 ║     1 ║   0 ║      0 ║ achene     ║ Arial    ║       12 ║  121.1 ║  83.42 ║  71.04 ║     12 ║           ║
║    1 ║     1 ║   1 ║      0 ║ capsule    ║ Arial    ║       12 ║  121.1 ║ 124.82 ║ 101.07 ║     12 ║           ║
║    1 ║     1 ║   2 ║      0 ║ caryopsis  ║ Arial    ║       12 ║  121.1 ║ 207.65 ║ 140.31 ║     12 ║           ║
║    2 ║     2 ║   0 ║      0 ║ cypsela    ║ Arial    ║       12 ║   85.1 ║  69.62 ║  24.36 ║     12 ║           ║
║    3 ║     3 ║     ║        ║            ║          ║          ║        ║        ║        ║        ║           ║
║    4 ║     4 ║   0 ║      0 ║ fibrous    ║ Arial    ║       12 ║ 276.29 ║ 239.45 ║  95.42 ║     12 ║ Bold      ║
║    4 ║     4 ║   1 ║      1 ║ follicle   ║ Arial    ║       12 ║  121.1 ║ 266.81 ║ 229.57 ║     12 ║           ║
║    4 ║     4 ║   1 ║      1 ║ legume     ║ Arial    ║       12 ║ 353.94 ║ 266.81 ║ 155.71 ║     12 ║           ║
║    4 ║     4 ║   2 ║      2 ║ loment     ║ Arial    ║       12 ║   85.1 ║ 294.41 ║  165.1 ║     12 ║           ║
║    4 ║     4 ║   2 ║      2 ║ nut        ║ Arial    ║       12 ║ 253.43 ║ 294.41 ║  14.39 ║     12 ║           ║
║    4 ║     4 ║   2 ║      2 ║ samara     ║ Arial    ║       12 ║ 271.04 ║ 294.41 ║ 255.64 ║     12 ║           ║
║    4 ║     4 ║   3 ║      0 ║ schizocarp ║ Arial    ║       12 ║   85.1 ║ 501.43 ║ 432.97 ║     12 ║           ║
║    5 ║     5 ║   0 ║      0 ║ silicle    ║ Arial    ║       12 ║   85.1 ║  69.62 ║ 363.44 ║     12 ║           ║
║    5 ║     5 ║   1 ║      1 ║ utricle    ║ Arial    ║       12 ║   85.1 ║  83.42 ║ 382.36 ║     12 ║           ║
║    6 ║     6 ║     ║        ║            ║          ║          ║        ║        ║        ║        ║           ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════╩════════╩════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════════╝
```

This is the xml file:

```
<document>
    <page index="0"/>
    <page index="1">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="83.42" width="71.04" height="12.00">achene</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="124.82" width="101.07" height="12.00">capsule</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="207.65" width="140.31" height="12.00">caryopsis</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="2">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="69.62" width="24.36" height="12.00">cypsela</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="3"/>
    <page index="4">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" fontStyle="Bold" x="276.29" y="239.45" width="95.42" height="12.00">fibrous drupe</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="266.81" width="229.57" height="12.00">follicle</text></column>
             <column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="353.94" y="266.81" width="155.71" height="12.00">legume</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="294.41" width="165.10" height="12.00">loment – a type of indehiscent legume</text></column>
             <column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="253.43" y="294.41" width="14.39" height="12.00">nut</text></column>
             <column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="271.04" y="294.41" width="255.64" height="12.00">samara</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="501.43" width="432.97" height="12.00">schizocarp</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="5">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="69.62" width="363.44" height="12.00">silicle</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="83.42" width="382.36" height="12.00">utricle</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="6"/>
</document>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close enough:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

etree = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for j in etree.iter('page'):
    for i in  j.iter('text'):        
        dfcols = ['index','text','fontName','fontSize','x','y','width','height','fontStyle']
        df = df.append(pd.Series([j.get('index'),i.text,i.get('fontName'),i.get('fontSize'),i.get('x'),i.get('y'),i.get('width'),i.get('height'),i.get('fontStyle')],index=dfcols), ignore_index=True)

df = df[dfcols]
df.head()
```

Output:

```
 index  text          fontName fontSize x       y      width    height  fontStyle
0   1   achene         Arial    12.0    121.10  83.42   71.04   12.00   None
1   1   capsule        Arial    12.0    121.10  124.82  101.07  12.00   None
2   1   caryopsis      Arial    12.0    121.10  207.65  140.31  12.00   None
3   2   cypsela        Arial    12.0    85.10   69.62   24.36   12.00   None
4   4   fibrous drupe  Arial    12.0    276.29  239.45  95.42   12.00   Bold
```

Comment: Thank you Jack for your help. Your solution is very close. But how add the columns for nodes `row` and `column` related with each text line?

Comment: @GerCas - Unfortunately, `row` and `column` don't have built in numbers (unlike the `index` of `page`), which means you'll have to manually set two counters - one for each row of each page and one for each column of each row, and then incorporate them into the dataframe as two more columns. It's doable, but will take some work and make the code somewhat more complicated.